# Multi Node Cluster in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, multi-master-replication

Is there a way we can setup multinode cluster in Postgres like Oracle RAC:

*Oracle RAC allows multiple computers to run Oracle RDBMS software simultaneously while accessing a single database, thus providing clustering.*

So far I went through several articles but it seems Postgres does not support it. 
PGPool is the only way we can do load balancing but it won't be same as RAC.

Comment: [You probably don't need RAC to begin with](https://www.ashnik.com/you-probably-dont-need-rac-you-mostly-dont-need-rac/) RAC still uses a single storage, so it does not scale writes either. You can achieve the same in Postgres with a hot standby and pgPool - all writes go to the same node. It's even better than RAC then as the I/O load for reading is actually distributed over two servers rather than one.

Comment: I do not want HA and I do not want to replicate same data to another node.

Comment: But that's what a RAC does